# Using list of functions to call async in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, future

I have bunch of static functions which I am using in async call and passing string x to function.

```
 std::future<void> f1 = std::async(std::launch::async, f001, x);
 std::future<void> f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, f002, x);
 std::future<void> f3 = std::async(std::launch::async, f003, x);
```

and then calling get on each.

```
 f1.get(); f2.get(); f3.get();
```

If we consider I have ten functions and doing same looks repetitive to me.

I tried to create list of function pointers and called above functions, like following.

```
 std::vector<void (*) (std::string)> funs;
 funs.push_back(foo1);
 funs.push_back(foo2);
 funs.push_back(foo3);

 std::vector<std::future<void>> tasks
 for(auto& t : temp ){
    task.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, t, x);)
 }
 for(auto task : tasks){
    task.get();
 }
```

but it is giving me errors like delete functions and similar.

Is there better way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: The provided code does not compile.

Comment: `for(auto task : tasks)` -> `for(auto& task : tasks)`

Comment: @lisyarus I already mentioned that code  giving me error.

Comment: @RohitVyavahare it has undeclared variables and semicolons missing or put in wrong places. Fixing this would help getting a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take the tasks by reference:

```
 for(auto& task : tasks){
    task.get();
 }
```

You should have seen something related to `future(const future&) = delete;` in an error message.

Comment: Using `for(auto&& task : tasks)` also works for all cases if you ever were to use a container that returns objects by value